# Form Action's PHP file not working

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a simple form that's supposed to enter submissions in a MySQL database but whenever the form is submitted I get a server 500 error. I'm new to the PHP/MySQL so i'm not seeing the problem. Any ideas?

**HTML Form Excerpt:**

```
<form method="post" action="submit.php">
  <label for="fname">First Name *:</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" /><br />
  <label for="lname">Last Name *:</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" /><br />
  <label for="email">Email *:</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" /><br />
  <label for="phone">Phone Number:</label>
    <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" /><br />
  <input type="checkbox" id="ageverify" />
    <label for="ageverify">I am at least 18 years of age *</label><br />
  <input type="checkbox" id="terms" />
    <label for="terms">I agree to the Terms &amp; Conditions *</label><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**Entirety of submit.php**

```
<?
mysql_connect("localhost","USERNAME","PASSWORD");
mysql_select_db("DB_NAME");

$sql = "INSERT into entries (fname,lname,email,phone,ageverify,terms) "; 
$sql .= "VALUES ("; 
$sql .= $_POST['fname'] . ',' . $_POST['lname'] . ',' . $_POST['email'] . ','; 
$sql .= $_POST['phone'];

if (isset($_POST['ageverify']) // if checked will exist, otherwise it won't 
$sql .= 'yes' . ','; 
else 
$sql .= 'no' . ','; 

if (isset($_POST['terms']) 
$sql .= 'yes' . ','; 
else 
$sql .= 'no' . ','; 

$sql .= ')'; 

$result = mysql_query($sql); 

if($result){
    echo("Thanks");
} else{
    echo("Something went wrong");
}
?>
```

---

**UPDATE: WORKING CODE (As rudimentary as it may be)**

```
<?php 
mysql_connect("localhost","USERNAME","PASSWORD");
mysql_select_db("DB_NAME");

$sql = "INSERT into entries (fname,lname,email,phone,ageverify,terms) "; 
$sql .= "VALUES ("; 
$sql .= '"' . $_POST['fname'] . '"' . ',' . '"' . $_POST['lname'] . '"' . ',' . '"' . $_POST['email'] . '"' . ','; 
$sql .= '"' . $_POST['phone'] . '"'; 

if (isset($_POST['ageverify'])) // if checked will exist, otherwise it won't 
$sql .= ',' . '"yes"' ; 
else 
$sql .= ',' . '"no"'; 

if (isset($_POST['terms'])) 
$sql .= ',' . '"yes"'; 
else 
$sql .= ',' . '"no"'; 

$sql .= ')'; 

echo $sql; 

$result = mysql_query($sql); 

if($result){ 
echo("Thanks"); 
} else{ 
echo("Something went wrong"); 
} 
?>
```

Comment: -1 for not understanding your problem.

Comment: Is there a .htaccess-file anywhere? Have you tried to use the correct php tags like `<?php // your script ?>` ?

Comment: What's not to understand? This is his code, it generates a 500 error. Seems pretty straight forward to me.

Comment: @Olof: If you think the post needs improvement, say how. Your comment has no value.

Comment: (1) SQL Injection - read up on it, don't build SQL off raw form input.  (2) The command `yes` or `no` isn't understood by MySQL, if that's supposed to be text it should be surrounded by quotes (`$sql.="'yes',"`) (3) Debug - Before `$result=...` try `echo $sql;exit();` run that SQL directly against the DB to see the result/if there's an SQL syntax error - if you don't even get output then PHP isn't configured/operating correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: **Read up on SQL injection!** You are definitely vulnerable!

Second, you should [enable error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) while developing - this would have told what was wrong.

The status 500 appears because something serverside went wrong. You can check your error logs, when this occurs.

Though, if you enable error reporting, you get the errors on screen. This would have told you that you have syntax errors.
You are missing ending parentheses on line 11 and 16:

```
if (isset($_POST['ageverify'])
```

should be

```
if (isset($_POST['ageverify']))
```

And the same goes for line 16.

Thirdly, always start PHP tags with `<?php` and NOT just `<?`. Try avoiding short tags.

Comment: This is all very true, but wouldn't the 500 error have occurred before the PHP file was even parsed? Or, am I wrong about that?

Comment: @Madmartigan I'm not sure I follow? If the PHP file is the reason as to why the status 500 error uccors, then no - the error comes _while_ parsing.

Comment: How would one trigger a 500 with a syntax error, or with PHP in any way? Maybe I'm daft, but I didn't think that was possible.

Comment: If you disable error reporting in PHP and write something that won't parse (or throws an exception) PHP makes apache react with an internal server error. If error reporting is enables, errors are printed to the screen, only with 200 OK instead.

Comment: The missing parentheses seemed to be causing the error. Appreciate the help. This is just my first exercise and I'll start expanding on it with injection prevention and entry verification among others. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

The error log would be extremly helpfull in this case, but suspect the "," after the last "yes/no" to be the problem:

```
if (isset($_POST['terms']) 
$sql .= 'yes'; 
else 
$sql .= 'no';
```

The Syntax for Values is (Value1,Value2,...,ValueN).

Edit: And you are missing a closing bracket on lines 11 and 16. You should get an editor that validates the code you write. Saves you a lot of trouble.

Comment: There is no problem with his concatenation; although not pretty, there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Are you sure? That last "," tends to break stuff in MySql. Maybe I'm confusing this with IN().

Comment: Well, the SQL will probably fail too, but the concatenation isn't wrong. The SQL query might be, but the question was why his scripts returns a status 500.

Answer (score 1):

A 500 error means the server is down, or otherwise not accessible.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error

I'm assuming the connect and db parameters in your posted code were intentionally placed on here as generic entries and not what you're really using, right?  Since you said you're new, the parameters of USERNAME, PASSWORD and DB_NAME aren't what you really use literally... you need to put in a real user, password and db name.

Comment: Of course. I took out the sensitive info for the post. I'm not sure what the server error is about. The HTML file the form in on is in the same directory as the PHP and it works.

Comment: The comma in your yes/no concatenation is in the wrong place, it should be before, not after.

Comment: There are a few things to clean up first:
1. Your opening PHP bracket should be "<?php"
2. The comma in your final yes/no concatenation isn't needed since it's the last parameter
3. Your IF statements are missing their closing parentheses
4. At least one of your IFs could be failing since you have more than one line in the ELSE and you're not using curly braces.

Clean up your code and try it again.